# Co-word analysis of instagram hashtags in R

Tags: r, hashtag

I have collected data from Instagram based on a search of two hashtags: 
posts with hashtagA (=1) and posts with hashtagB (=2), coded in 'group'.

My data frame looks like this at the moment:
one row is one post.

```
group   hashtags
1   #something #anything #sunnyday
1   #wokeuplikethis #Monday
1   #something  #Monday #yolo
2   #yolo #Monday #hustle 
2   #sunnyday #lake #work
2   #yolo #rock #hustle
1   #anything
2   #anything #new
```

I guess I need a nested data structure (1 post with several hashtags) to analyze co-occuring hashtags and get a network of hashtags that often appear together. 
What code / package could you recommend to conduct a co-word analysis with this minimal reproducible data set?

Comment: Thx for the Info, I edited and refined the question!